# How to test that my server is indeed in 1gbps connection?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I ordered a server and the host say I got 1gbps connection

However, because I set up the server incorrectly, the speed drop to 10mbps

I think now it has been fixed. But I want to make sure.

This is what my host told me

> It has nothing to do with FDCServers in particular..  Its an issue
>   that sometimes can occur when a NIC on a computer negotiates it's
>   speed with a switch. It's something that can happen from time to time
>   and part of basic troubleshooting.
>
> If you are running linux you can type run the commands man ethtool or
>   man mii-tool
>
> And if you'd like to learn about basic network information.  I'm sure
>   a quick google search can provide some information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the speed information on your `eth0` device using `ethtool`:

```
ethtool eth0
```

substitute the device you are actually using for `eth0`.

In the past I have seen trouble with devices not connecting at the full speed, but more often not a Full Duplex connection, because of some server-hardware/switch incompatibility. Often `ethtool` would help to fix that with `ethtool --change eth0 duplex full` or `ethtool --change eth0 speed 1000`.